# Is there a quick way to select a group of faces that are all pointed the same way?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, faces, selection-tools, select

trying to model tree limbs and want to select all faces that are at the end of the branch. Since it is circular I have to select some of them manually. Is there a fast way to select them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope i understood you right, so you could do this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Additionally, you can set a higher _Threshold_ value in the options menu appearing at the bottom of the window when you use the tool. This way you can also choose polygons that are facing _mostly_ in the same direction but not _exactly_ (a little deviation is already allowed there by default).